# Does $(p \land q) \rightarrow q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A valid rule of inference is the following so-called simplification:

$(p \land q)\rightarrow p$ (a tautology).

For ($p \land q$) to be true, both $p$ and $q$ must be **True**. Therefore, we can conclude that $p$ is **True**.

**Question**

Does this mean that ($p \land q) \rightarrow q$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: What happens if $q$ is true? What if it's false?

Answer (score 2):

You can (alternatively) apply the following reasoning:
\begin{align*}
(p\wedge q)\to p & \Longleftrightarrow \neg(p\wedge q)\vee p\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee\neg q)\vee p\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p \vee p)\vee \neg q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \top\vee \neg q
\end{align*}

where the last expression is a tautology.

Hopefully this helps!